# Connecting to Oracle database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

Today is my first day trying to use Oracle databases in Asp.NET so I have no idea of what I need to do.

I have added this code

```
Dim oOracleConn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection()
oOracleConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxx;User Id=yyy;Password=psw;"
oOracleConn.Open()
Response.write("Connected to Oracle.")
oOracleConn.Close()
oOracleConn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

But it gives me the error

> Type 'OracleConnection' is not defined.

Now i've had a look on the internet and it says that it may be the reference to the DLL that is missing?

I know I have got a DLL reference in my page and I don't think I even have the DLL anywhere on my server.

Where do I get this DLL from?

I've downloaded the ODBC .NET data provider but this didn't seem to help.

I've tried to add a reference in Visual Studio but I can't find the Oracle client reference in the list.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the Oracle Data Provider for .NET? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

Comment: Just installing it now thanks :)

Comment: I seem to just be getting this error now `TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

Comment: You have to check your tnsnames.ora file I think. Something is wrong there or your connectionstring is incorrect.

Comment: Ok I think it's most probably the connection string - i'll have a look thanks :)

Comment: I think i've got the connection string correct now as its not giving errors but it seems to be taking forever to do anything I haven't had any data back from it yet

Comment: Can you check the Windows Eventlog?

Comment: @Rhapsody it turns out that the tnsname.ora wasn't set up properly - Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle recommended method is to use the [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

You'll need an Oracle Client that is compatible with the version of the database you are using installed on your dev machine and the web sever machine.

There are some quirks with how you have to specify the database connection string. Some kind internet soul has [documented](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) the database connection strings for the oracle providers.

The oracle client has a file, called TNSNAMES.ORA, which is typically located in the /NETWORK/ADMIN folder under the oracle home where the client was installed (the installation location varies by version and installation settings).

This file contains a list of databases with the Port Number, Hostname, and Oracle SID which allows the oracle client to make a connection to a server.

Once all of this is configured (or you decide to use the "TNS-less" connection string), you should be able to make database connections to oracle.

The ODP.NET provider documentation also provides some sample code which is very helpful when getting started with it.

Comment: Thanks for this information it turned out that the TNSNAMES.ORA was the fault in my case - it hadn't been set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx), this OracleConnection is an obsolete API, however the DLL being used is:

```
System.Data.OracleClient.dll
```

EDIT: This [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajeshnk/OracleConnectivityInNet11302005055528AM/OracleConnectivityInNet.aspx) provides some data on different API's to connect to Oracle with .NET

Comment: What should I be using instead of OracleConnection? I got that code from somewhere on the internet

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is data type mapping,but not connection or provider .